# How to patch add in Fugitive plugin?

Tags: neovim, plugin-system, plugin-fugitive

This screen I got after running the `:Gstatus` command:

[image]

Then I moved the cursor to `init.vim` file and pressed the `p` key, i.e. run `git add –patch` for the current file.

Now I have this screen:

[image]

As you can see, here's the usual interaction for git add patch in a terminal. In the terminal I can press `y` to add the current chunk of code to the stage area, press `n` to skip the current one and so on.

But here in `fugitive.vim` I can't figure out what I should press. Should I press `:w` to add the current chunk to stage? Or should I press `-`, or `:q` to skip?

P.S. I'm using Neovim

Comment: See if this [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-working-with-the-git-index/) is helpful

Comment: Also, what happens if you experiment a bit?

Comment: When I try this in my vim (not nvim) I get booted out to the full terminal, then when finished it takes me back to vim.

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble, forgot to mention, i'm under neovim, it's not booting out to the terminal

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Short Answer

Just use the normal interactive buttons. In (regular) vim, pressing <kbd>p</kbd> drops you into the interactive terminal patch, so it's the interface you're used to.

For neovim users: Just enter insert mode (<kbd>i</kbd>), then it works as a terminal, the cursor goes to 'stage this hunk...' line.

In newer versions, you can use <kbd>P</kbd> instead, and the interface is builtin (not an external terminal).

## Long Answer: Don't use `p`!

If you're already using [plugin-fugitive](/questions/tagged/plugin-fugitive), I'd highly recommend learning how to use it <strike>properly</strike> powerfully.

From the `:Git` window, you can trigger a number of commands.

> *Pro tip:* <kbd>)</kbd> moves to the next file in the window (and <kbd>(</kbd> previous). `g?` brings up a list of other shortcuts.

[Another answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21410/10604) covers recent updates to the status window that may be even easier to use for patch-like adding than the diff method below, using `-` and `=`. This is my preferred method.

You can hit <kbd>dd</kbd> on any file to bring up a `:Gdiffsplit` window. This window will show you the differences between the file on disk and the file in the git index. You add pieces to the git index (simulating `git add --patch`), but in a much more "vim-like" way.

> *Pro tip:* in any vimdiff window (including `:Gdiffsplit`), use `]c` and `[c` to jump between diffs

The working copy is always on the **right**, and the version in the index is always on the **left**. Note that updating the index ('patching' pieces of the file) is as simple as pulling changes from the working copy to the index. We have the commands `do` and `dp` for this. Which to run depends on where you are.

- `do` (or 'diff-obtain'--`:diffget`) *pulls* the nearby diff over from the other side
- `dp` (or 'diff-put'--`:diffput`) *puts* the nearby diff in the other side

The result? From the working copy, use `dp` to add changes you want to stage, or `do` to reset changes. (You can actually also run these from the index, but it's slightly less intuitive to me.)

`:diffget` and `:diffput` work with ranges (read: visual mode), if you don't want to stage an entire diff hunk at once.

> *Tip:* if the colors look weird, try `:diffupdate`

### I added changes to the index, now what?

Write the **index** file (e.g. `:w`) and watch the status window update!

#### References

- [Vimcast on fugitive and the git index](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-working-with-the-git-index/)
- Fugitive help
- Vim help

Comment: I wish neovim could go to terminal, much easier for me

Comment: @megas Yeah I'm not sure how fugtive handles neovim (it's not called out in the docs). My other comment still remains--what happens if you try pushing the 'regular' buttons (y,n,q) ? (Or adapt to a different way of 'patching')

Comment: Finally I found the answer! Just enter insert mode (i), then it works as a terminal, the cursor goes to 'stage this hunk...' line

Comment: Much helpful, the `:diffput` and `:diffget` part @D.BenKnoble

Comment: I just learned a ton. Thank you @D.BenKnoble.

Comment: If you're also using `vim-gitgutter`, you can stage changes from the file itself before going into commit workflow (default mapping is `<leader>hs`), while also navigating between hunks with `[c` and `]c`.

Comment: +1 for linking to the VimCasts video

Comment: With the new update, I can use `:Git` to enter the status window and then trigger inline diff with `=` and add hunk to stage by `s` while cursor on hunk

Answer (score 13):

Here's another way to do it, all within **fugitive**. I believe some of this is new with the 3.0 release on Aug 20, 2019. Someone had created a "What's New?" video, which I sadly can't find now. The `:Git` command received a **lot** of attention.

In the `:Git` window, you can use these subcommands. There are many others, but these serve me well.

- `<C-N>` or `<C-P>` to jump to the next/previous file (as mentioned above)
- `-` on a file, stages (or unstages) the entire file.
- `=` shows the `git diff` of the file your cursor is on.
- `-` on a hunk, stages (or unstages) the hunk.
- `-` in a visual selection, stages (or unstages) the selected lines in the hunk.
- `cvc` - commits the staged changes in verbose mode. I like the last chance it gives me to verify the right changes have been staged, and it helps inform the commit message.

I really like the inline diffing in the `:Git` window. For me, it's easier than dealing with the separate windows and the `do` and `dp` commands.

Before I learned this, I would always go to the shell and do a `git commit -pv`, but now I can stay entirely in Vim.

Comment: `:Gstatus` has been replaced with `:Git status` and the above behavior does not seem to still exist.

Comment: Actually, it's the new `:Git` command that opens the window. `:Git status` just echoes the status to the screen without opening a new window. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks, I saw a lot of references to `:Gstatus` but no mention that the interactive window was now accessed through `:Git`, great! :)

Comment: Didn't know about the "visual selection + `-` operator", but it's exactly what I needed. Thanks!